# Why don't I get proximity alterts even though I've registered alerts?

Tags: java, android, android-location

I'm trying to simply set a proximity later for an area an for testing, I simply added this to the `onCreate` method of my main activity.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bndBundle) {

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(WidgetService.ACTION_STOP_PROXIMITY); 
    registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);

    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Intent ittIntent = new Intent(this, ProximityIntentReceiver.class);
    ittIntent.putExtra(WidgetService.KEY_STOP_IDENTIFIER, 1000);
    PendingIntent pitIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, ittIntent, 0);
    locManager.addProximityAlert(60.15769, 24.94150, 150, -1, pitIntent);

    super.onCreate(bndBundle);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

}
```

..and here's the simple receiver class that I'm using

```
public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
        Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

        if (entering) {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "entering");
        }
        else {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "exiting");
        }

    }

}
```

I'm testing this on my emulator and when I use the DDMS console to set the co-ordinates of the phone manually, I still don't see the log message.

My manifest file doesn't have any special code. I've added the correct permissions and have the code for a simple activity- no services or anything.

I read through a whole bunch of posts on StacKOverflow but I haven't been able to resolve the issue. Am I missing something in my snippet?

Answer (score 1):

You are registering this receiver dynamically, through `registerReceiver()`, to have it respond to broadcasts whose action string is `WidgetService.ACTION_STOP_PROXIMITY`.

However, the actual broadcast you are sending is trying to use an explicit `Intent`, identifying your receiver class. This does not line up with the `IntentFilter` that you are using with `registerReceiver()`.

Either:

- Register your receiver in the manifest and get rid of `registerReceiver()`, in which case your explicit `Intent` will work, or
- Use `new Intent(WidgetService.ACTION_STOP_PROXIMITY)` instead of `new Intent(this, ProximityIntentReceiver.class)`, so your `Intent` lines up with your `IntentFilter`

You cannot use explicit `Intent` objects to send broadcasts to receivers registered via `registerReceiver()`. An explicit `Intent` will only work with a manifest-registered receiver.

Comment: Thats's exactly what I was doing earlier but it still doesn't work. I'm not creating the like using `new Intent(WidgetService.ACTION_STOP_PROXIMITY)`. The rest of the code is the same but the log messages still don't show as if the method was never really triggered.

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla: Try calling `send()` on your `PendingIntent` once in addition to using it with `addProximityAlert()`. If you still are not getting log messages, then your problem still lies with your `BroadcastReceiver` and `PendingIntent`, or perhaps that the whole proximity alert setup code is not being called. If you get a log message from your manual `send()`, but not from the proximity alerts, then you have some other problem. Try `adb shell dumpsys location` to confirm that your proximity alert is actually registered.

Comment: When I run the `adb shell dumpsys location`, I can see that that application is in the list of Geofences and the co-ordinates are correct. When i sent the `PendingIntent`, the receiver worked just fine which now leaves equally as lost wondering why it doesn't trigger the intent. I've wiped the emulator clean and that didn't help either.

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla: If you are using the emulator, how are you testing this?

Comment: Once I start my application in Eclipse. I go to the DDMS perspective and type in the latitude and longitude coordinates and press "Set". It seems to set the coordinates corecctly because when I opened the Maps application, I can see the location. Shouldn't this trigger an proximity alert?

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla: I would expect it to, but, then again, I have not messed with proximity alerts in years.

Comment: I think I'll just pass on this for now. It's taken up way too much time already. Thanks for all your help CommonsWare.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you type in the right coordinates. in DDMS they're reversed, longitude first, then latitude